# So where can I find the best online C++ Standard Library reference?

Tags: c++, stl, reference, standard-library, std

You know, with comments and examples and stuff.

Need a quick reference for when coding.

Comment: +1 for not calling it "the STL"

Comment: Yeah I noticed the bickering in other questions.

Comment: I won't say [the one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct1as7hw.aspx) is the best, but I like it.

Comment: @Benjamin: So why don't you make that an answer? It seems as valid as mine.

Comment: @Tomalak: Who calls it "the STL"? The STL is not the whole Standard Library. (Though it is the *coolest* part hehe)

Comment: @Billy: _Loads_ of people unfortunately. My minions do their best to fix these errors across SO, but I see it all the time. e.g. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5647543/1), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541022/please-help-with-stl-stringstream), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/setting-the-internal-buffer-used-by-a-standard-stream-pubsetbuf). It baffles me that this is so often denied. Anyway, I guess this question may not be the place for this... [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about) is :D

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if I'd say it's "the best", but the online reference I use most often is the [Apache C++ Standard Library Reference Guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/). Maybe people use SGI's [Standard Template Library Programmer's Guide](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).

Update:

These days, I mostly use [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of thing I was talking about.

Answer (score 13):

Along with a copy of the standard, I use [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), mostly because it is the first result when I google `std::vector`.

Update:

These days, I mostly use [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself. ;-)

Comment: I liked `cplusplus.com`'s presentation better than `cppreference.com`'s one (in the meanwhile, got used to the latter's one as well), so I preferred the former, too -- *until* having to discover that it hasn't been up to date several times already. Since then, cppreference only.

Answer (score 5):

Do yourself a favour, and buy a book, such as [The C++ Standard Library](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/index.html).

Comment: 1) "Buy" != free (as the original post asked for).   2) "book" != online.  You can't search (among other things).    I have the C++ Prog Lang w/ 2011 (latest Stroustrup), and I love it, but it is falling apart due to its own weight not being held by the binding, FOR the amount of constant usage it receives.  The copy I have has been repaired multiple times -- binding reglued, pages reglued w/wood glue, & various types of clear tape to hold pages and cover where glue wouldn't work.  It's still falling apart.  A book is not a substitute for an electronic reference, no matter how good the book.

Answer (score 4):

The actual C++ Standard. Seriously. It's kind of expensive, but it's the only authoritative source out there. If you need specific docs on something <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> works just fine.

Comment: The draft of the new C++0x standard is [available freely](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf) and makes an excellent general reference, though of course if in doubt you'll have to refer to the eventual published standard. Also: "Is it true that nobody owns the C++ standard?" -- "Probably, given the price."

Comment: @Kerrek: That is not the latest draft. The FCD was available for a while but was removed at the request of the International Standards Organization.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is the one I linked to sufficient though as a day-to-day reference?

Comment: @Kerrek: Depends. Are you a compiler developer? :)

Comment: Haha, no! Exactly - if I just want to write "normal" C++ code without exploiting the dark alleys of unexpected language behaviour, would that downloadable reference be sufficiently accurate and complete? It has a great STL reference, that alone would be worth a recommendation if there aren't any glaring differences to the actual standard.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup links this [newer working paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) from his C++11-FAQ and says it's "close" to the FCD.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I rely on mainly on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)